# How to add user made scripts to EC2 ubuntu?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an EC2 instance on AWS and I want to transfer some scripts into the site-packages of python3. I can't seem to find a way to do this. Some functions from these files are used by the scripts I am looking to run.

I tried SFTP but it wont allow me to get into the folder just tried to download it.

I am on Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify which user are you logging into EC2 server. Is "ubuntu" user (created by  default) or did you create a new user?

Comment: @Josir user is ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option to install any service or program in python on a linux server is to create a regular user and then create a virtualenv on a private directory. There, you can freely install any script or package and give the proper rights to specific services/directories of your server.

Install also basic packages in order to run python environment:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python-dev python-setuptools zlib1g-dev python-pip
```

Comment: Thanks Josir I will create a virutalenv.